# C drive full after reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

So i've used the windows 7 usb/dvd download tool and added a windows 8.1 iso to it, it downloaded the things to the usb and I booted the computer, went to the bios configured the booting, and after downloading windows 8. to the pc I noticed my C drive was 8GB free out of 297GB. I didn't download anything yet. Help!

Comment: First you have to help us: what's filling the drive, and maybe we can tell you where it came from (if it isn't immediately obvious). What we cannot do is tell you what is filling your drive.

Comment: Uhmm It's resolved. It was the pagefile.sys

Answer (score -1):

**Hey there, welcome to Super User!**

Did you format the C drive? This may have happened because you may forgot to format the drive. There is no other way this could happen as you may have got like 30GB out of 297GB before, when the Windows system files are over 20GB. While upgrading to another operating system, remember that first you have to format your C drive as it's the main one.